# Brunn-Minkowski Inequality : A Partucular Example of a 2 dimensional set.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, functional-inequalities

I have an inequality - $(R_{C+D})^{2} \geqslant (R_{C})^{2} + (R_{D})^{2}$. Representing it as  $((R_{C+D})^{4})^{1/2} \geqslant ((R_{C})^{4})^{1/2} + ((R_{D})^{4})^{1/2}$, it follows from Brunn-Minkowski inequality relating two sets, C and D with their volumes that these sets exist in a 2-dimensional space with some addition operation between its elements, where volume of the set goes to $vol(C) \propto (R_{C})^{4} $ where $R_{C}$ represents some parameter representing set C. Elements of set C are functions of $R_{C}$ along with some other parameter, if required.
I was wondering if there is any particular example of a 2-dimensional set or if there is any procedure to construct or if there exists some representation of it. And also what is the addition operation defined on such set. 
Thanks.

Comment: what is $R^2_C$, $R^2_D$ and $R^2_{C+D}$?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I've presented the question more carefully now.